# How can I place a FloatLayout within a GridLayout using kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm usng kivy and the kv languge to make a GUI, I'm still only new to kivy.
In the image below the the buttons were in the black bit on the right side of the GUI but the scrollview buttons on fitted half of the height of the screen to I put an extra floatlayout in the  rule and indented everything but now all the buttons are on the wrong side of the screen.

```
#:kivy 1.9.0
GridLayout:
    rows: 1

    LeftArea:
    RightArea:

<LeftArea@FloatLayout>:

    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 0, 1, 0
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    Image:
        source: 'moneyswags.gif'
        size: self.size
        pos: self.pos


<RightArea@GridLayout>:
    cols: 1
    size_hint_x: 0.3
    spacing: '10dp'

    FloatLayout:
        ScrollView:
            LinksGrid:
                id: links_grid

        BoxLayout:
            cols: 1
            rows: 2
            GetLinksButton:
                links_grid: links_grid
            Clearlinkbuttons:
                links_grid: links_grid

<LinksGrid@GridLayout>:
    cols: 1
    spacing: '5dp'
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height

<GetLinksButton>:
    size_hint_y: 0.1
    text: 'get links'
    on_press: self.get_links()

<Clearlinkbuttons>:
    size_hint_y: 0.1
    text: 'clear links'
    on_press: self.clear_links()

<LinkButton>:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: '80dp'
```

[image: kivv]

Comment: Please post a small *working* example...

Comment: How about reading a tutorial instead of asking for every single detail while building your app? If you don't know how float layout works, then read it in the docs.

Comment: Please check the [Crash Course](http://inclem.net/pages/kivy-crash-course/). It'll help you with learning kivy.